# Sending Email on PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am trying to send an email on PhoneGap. I've seen a few different EmailComposer plugins, but I wanted to see if there was a simpler way to send an email without a plugin. I've tried using the mailto command like this:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello">Send Mail</a>
```

When I run this on the iPhone simulator and click on the link I get this message in the console log:

AppDelegate::shouldStartLoadWithRequest: Received Unhandled URL mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again

Is it possible to use the mailto command to send an email or do I need to use a plugin? If I can use the mailto command what can I change to make it work? Also, what would be the advantage to using a plugin versus the mailto command?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the phonegap plugin **EmailComposer** .

Mailto command won't work on all platforms. That's the reason why this plugin is mostly used.

[Github link](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer)

All the guidelines to use it can be found at it's readme.txt

Comment: For anyone else that has this question. I found that using this repository [https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/EmailComposer] works better for the version of PhoneGap I'm using, which is 2.2.0.

Comment: For those who come after: All the above mentioned Github links are dead. As of Phonegap 3.0 this is the best plugin - https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

Answer (score 0):

I myself wanted to send a mail from a phonegap app and didnt want to go for a plugin. So I have thought of this solution to send a mail.

- Send an ajax request to a server side script that can send mails (like PHP - that is what my server side scripts are written in).
- In the data for the ajax request, send all the data you want in the mail, body, attachments etc.
- Construct the mail in PHP and send the mail.
- On successful send, respond back with a JSON object indicating the status.
- Use the callback function of the ajax script to provide the user a notification about the same (success or failure).

I will share the code, if this works, as soon as I am done with it.